# Getting next iteration value instead of currently in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiynapp that updates a plot using the reactiveTimer, so it creates an animation effect. But, I'm having a problem: The iterator is getting the next iteration value. Bellow there's a simpler version of my code, that has the same issue.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('play','Play'),
  textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  timer <- reactiveTimer(1000)
  i <- 999 
  
  observeEvent(input$play,{
    i <<- 1
  })
  
  observe({
    timer()
    if(i <= 5){
      output$text <- renderText(paste0(i,'/5'))
      print(paste0(i,'/5'))
      i <<- i+1
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expected it to render like that:

> 1/5
> 2/5
> 3/5
> 4/5
> 5/5

That's what I'm getting in the console with the print function. But in the UI it is:

> 2/5
> 3/5
> 4/5
> 5/5
> 6/5

One solution would be to print render `i-1`, but it doesn't sound good at all. I couldn't found a more robust solution that solves this problem, can someone help me?

Comment: FYI: I've not seen nested `observe`/`reactive` blocks in production. I typically recommend against them; while they may work, I suspect they may not work *as expected* in all situations.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the info. I'll update my code to one that is not nested, but the issue still existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved `paste0(i, "/5")` outside of `renderText()` and it fixes your problem. As for why this works, but not `renderText(paste0())`, I cannot explain.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('play','Play'),
    textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    timer <- reactiveTimer(1000)
    i <- 999 
    
    observeEvent(input$play,{
        i <<- 1
    })
    
    observe({
        timer()
        if(i <= 5){
            counterText <- paste0(i,'/5')
            output$text <- renderText(counterText)
            print(paste0(i,'/5'))
            i <<- i+1
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked also in my more complex shinyapp, where the plots are stored in a vector. If I use an auxiliary variable `aux <- vec[[i]`] then call the auxiliary in the renderPlot `output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(aux)})`, it works. Probably the way that the render functions works are not as expect, I'm thinking about open an issue in the git.